# Difference in results with sparse solver

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, solver

I'm solving a non-linear elliptic PDE via linearization + iteration and a finite difference method: basically it comes down to solving a matrix equation **Ax = b**. **A** is a banded matrix. Due to the large size of **A** (typically ~8 billion elements) I have been using a sparse solver (`scipy.sparse.linalg.spsolve`) to do this. In my code, I compute a residual value which measures deviation from the true non-linear solution and lowers it with successive iterations. It turns out that there is a difference between the values that the sparse solver produces in comparison to what `scipy.linalg.solve` does.

---

Output of normal solver:

[image: normal solver output]

Output of sparse solver:

[image: sparse solver output]

---

The only difference in my code is the replacement of the solver. I don't think this is down to floating-point errors since the error creeps upto the 2nd decimal place (in the last iteration - but the order of magnitude also decreases... so I'm not sure). Any insights on why this might be happening? The final solution, it seems, is not affected qualitatively - but I wonder whether this can create problems.

*(No code has been included since the difference is only there in the creation of a sparse matrix and the sparse solver. However, if you feel you need to check some part of it, please ask me to include code accordingly)*

Comment: The differences don't look significant to me

Comment: @hpaulj As I've mentioned, they don't affect the solution qualitatively, but I'm interested in knowing why it happens at all + is there a possibility of this becoming significant in other applications. Also, in my particular application, I'd perhaps be worried if the residual eventually turns out to be 10^-15 instead of 10^-16, for instance, though it doesn't happen here.

Comment: The difference between the two solvers goes deeper than I care to explore. Click onn the`[source]` link on the respective documentations to see for yourself.

Comment: A difference of `1e-17` is well within what I'd expect from a float precision difference and the fact that two completely different solvers are that close seems like a success to me. If differences of that size are a problem for you, I would redesign my project from the ground up for numerical stability, as neither solver is likely to be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: @CJR thanks for your comment. This is enough.